# How to use current date pattern in log4j2 fileName?

Tags: java, tomcat, log4j, log4j2

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
    <Properties>
        <property name="filePattern">%d{yyyy-MM-dd}</property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="TEST"
                     fileName="application-${filePattern}.log"
                     filePattern="application-${filePattern}-rolled.log">
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy modulate="true"/>
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    ...
</Configuration>
```

I'd like to use the current date directly in the written logfile. But the result of the configuration above is `application-%{yyyy-MM-dd}` as filename.

Why is the date placeholder not resolved?
By the way: the renamed file on midnight is properly renamed like `application-2016-03-13-rolled.log`. Why does it work there, but not in the current logfile?

I'm running  `tomcat 8` and `java 8`, if that matters.

Answer (score 11):

Remove the filename attribute. It worked for me. (got the solution from: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-1859) Here is my working configuration

```
    <RollingFile name="File" filePattern="${basePath}/api_test_execution_log_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}_%d{HH-mm-ss}_%i.log" immediateFlush="true">
       <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>

       <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true"/>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="32 MB" />
            <OnStartupTriggeringPolicy/>
       </Policies>
    </RollingFile>
```

Comment: can I combine this with keep max 15 files or so? DefaultRolloverStrategy caused :: `RollingFileAppender 'MyAppender': When no file name is provided a DirectFileRolloverStrategy must be configured`

Answer (score 6):

This one worked (whyever):

```
<property name="filePattern">${date:yyyy-MM-dd}</property>
```

Comment: Yes, that worked fine for me: I had to define my appender this way: <RollingFile name="DailyRollingHTML" append="true" fileName="application-${filePattern}.log" filePattern="application-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why the placeholder isn't resolved but here is my working configuration:

```xml
<Appenders>
    <RollingFile name="Permament"
                 fileName="E:/workspace/myproject/logs/ergo.log"
                 filePattern="E:/workspace/myproject/logs/ergo.%d{yyyy-MM-dd.HH:mm}.log"
                 immediateFlush="true">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %5p{length=5} - %c{1} %m %ex%n"/>
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
        </Policies>
    </RollingFile>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

For those are using Log4j2 version 2.6.2 and below:

> The fileName is indeed a file name that never changes while the
> application is running. If you do not want this behavior upgrade to
> the latest version of Log4j 2 and do not specify the fileName
> attribute.

From https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-1859