# Log4j2 - Environment Lookup Failed - Environment Name not append to File Name

Tags: java, logging, environment-variables, log4j2

I have tried below log4j2 configuration to roll a log file daily. The log file name is on the environment variable. Below is my log4j2.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
  <Appenders>

    <!-- Console Appender -->
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss a} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
    </Console>

    <!-- Rolling File Appender -->
    <RollingFile name="RollingFile">
      <FileName>C:/MyLogDir/logs/${env:LOG_FILE_NAME}</FileName>
      <FilePattern>C:/MyLogDir/logs/job_log_collector.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.zip</FilePattern>
      <PatternLayout>
        <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss a} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</Pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
      <Policies>
        <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true" />
      </Policies>
      <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="5" />
    </RollingFile>

  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Logger name="com.package.name.AppName" level="debug" additivity="false">
      <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile" />
    </Logger>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

But I get below error while trying to get this run.

```
2020-05-06 23:03:27,130 main ERROR Unable to create file C:/MyLogDir/logs/${env:LOG_FILE_NAME} java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize0(Native Method)
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize(WinNTFileSystem.java:428)
    at java.io.File.getCanonicalPath(File.java:618)
    at java.io.File.getCanonicalFile(File.java:643)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.FileUtils.makeParentDirs(FileUtils.java:142)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$RollingFileManagerFactory.createManager(RollingFileManager.java:658)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$RollingFileManagerFactory.createManager(RollingFileManager.java:639)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractManager.getManager(AbstractManager.java:113)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager.getManager(OutputStreamManager.java:114)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager.getFileManager(RollingFileManager.java:209)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender$Builder.build(RollingFileAppender.java:146)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender$Builder.build(RollingFileAppender.java:62)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:122)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:1002)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:942)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:934)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:552)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:241)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:288)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:618)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:691)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.reconfigure(LoggerContext.java:708)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:263)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:153)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:45)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:194)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:602)
    at com.wiley.automation.JobLogCollector.App.<clinit>(App.java:11)
```

I tried both **${env:LOG_FILE_NAME}** and **$${env:LOG_FILE_NAME}**. 
But no luck.

Below dependencies used.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.13.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.13.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your configuration looks correct. If you have an environment variable defined named LOG_FILE_NAME this should be working. The Log4j EnvironmentLookup just calls System.getenv(key) where key would be "LOG_FILE_NAME". You should verify in your application that this variable is accessible in the environment. You could add `System.out.println(System.getEnv())` to your main method to print out all the environment variables.

You could also add status="debug" to your logging configuration but I doubt it will provide you with any more diagnostic information than what you already have.

Comment: Hi @rgoers. You are correct. I was running the program on Git Bash and it had different set of variable which caused the issue. It does work my way. Which the correct one is ${env:LOG_FILE_NAME}.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `env:` from your xml and try below given syntax

```
 <FileName>C:/MyLogDir/logs/${LOG_FILE_NAME}</FileName>
```

Comment: also can customize file name by using `pattern`. If you want to do it then please visit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35982475/how-to-use-current-date-pattern-in-log4j2-filename)

Comment: This format requires that LOG_FILE_NAME be defined as a property in the configuration. That property might be set via a lookup but it doesn't really solve the poster's issue that he cannot get the environment variable to resolve.

Comment: @rgoers It doesn't require a property to be set in the configuration. It will pick value from the environment variable.

Comment: Can you please tell me where that is documented? I certainly don't remember writing any code to implement that and the other committer who might have implemented it doesn't recall doing it either.  It is possible that if you have a log4j2-spring.xml file Spring might do it, but I haven't checked their documentation.  AFAIK the Log4j documentation only says it will look for the default value of that property in the properties section of the configuration.

Comment: Hi Guys, thanks for your support. I think above us not working. But it does work my way. Which is ${env:LOG_FILE_NAME} 
Problem was the java file ran by a different terminal which has different set of environment variables. ( I used git bash to run the jar and this caused the issue )
Thanks for your support again guys.