# how to change filename in my rolling file appender in my Java program

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

I want to change my filename in my rollingfile appender and add current date to it here is my config :

```
    <RollingFile
  name="rollingFile"
  fileName="logs/%d{YYYY-MM-DD}.application.log"
     filePattern="logs/application.%d{dd-MMM}.log.gz"
  ignoreExceptions="false">
  <PatternLayout>
      <Pattern>%m</Pattern>
  </PatternLayout>
  <Policies>
      <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1"/>
  </Policies>
  <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="5" />
</RollingFile>
```

but when I do this the file that is created for me in my logs folder is Like this :

> %d{YYYY-MM-DD}.application.log

why?
I just want to add my current date but log4j doesn't detect %d{YYYY-MM-DD} pattern and adds the exact string??!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand `fileName` should be the exact name of the log file before it is "rolled" (the active log file). The `filePattern` determines what the file is renamed to when it is rolled. Try setting `fileName` to just `logs/application.log` and use the date format you want for archived files in `filePattern`.

Comment: I Did it but nothing  changed. my file's name is the same as my fileName's attribute value in my xml config

Comment: It is supposed to be like that. What happens when the file is rolled? That is when the date pattern in filePattern is used.

Comment: Thanks I got it, but I want my unrolled files to have date in their name, what should I do?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35982475/how-to-use-current-date-pattern-in-log4j2-filename.